# Get device node by major/minor numbers pair

Tags: udev

Each device node under `/dev` has its own major/minor number pair. I know that we can retrieve this pair of numbers from the device node by means of `stat`, like this:

```
stat -c 'major: %t minor: %T' <file>
```

Or, `ls -l` also shows these numbers.

But how can we get device node(s) by given major and minor numbers? The only way I'm aware of is some kind of `ls -l` + `awk` trick, but I really hope there is better solution.

Comment: @mikeserv, yes I know that some devices can share these numbers, so in my initial question I've mentioned: "get device node(s)". Ideally I want to get a list with all device nodes whose major/minor numbers match, one node per line. That's strange we don't have a ready tool for that. Thanks for the answer btw!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a simpler approach using the *sys* pseudofilesystem, at */sys/dev* you have the devices ordered by type an then by major/minor, the file *uevent* contains the device name and a bunch of other info.

So for example,

```
  for file in $(find /sys/dev/ -name 7:0); do  
      source ${file}/uevent; echo $DEVNAME;
  done;
```

Echoes,

```
loop0
vcs
```

Note: This was tested in Debian Wheezy

Comment: to find backwards from dev name: `for file in $(ls /sys/dev/block/ ); do  
      source /sys/dev/block/${file}/uevent; 
 if [ "$DEVNAME" == "sda1" ] ; then
 echo ${file};
 fi
done;`

Answer (score 7):

Apparently it can be done more simply with `udevadm`, and I've just found out how.

To get the `DEVNAME` from `udevadm` you need only do:

```
udevadm info -rq name $PATH
```

For instance, if you wanted to know the `/dev` name for `/sys/dev/char/5:1` you'd do:

```
udevadm info -rq name /sys/dev/char/5:1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/dev/console
```

The `-r` option is to specify a `--root`ed path - without it the result above would read only `console`. The `-q` option specifies a database `--query` and it takes the operand `name` here - because we want the `DEVNAME`.

A very simple means of finding the path to a char and/or block device given only the major:minor numbers might look like:

```
mmdev() for d in /sys/dev/[cb]*/$1:$2
        do  [ -e "$d" ] || return
            printf %c:%s: "${d#/*/*/}" "${d##*/}"
            udevadm info -rq name "$d"
        done
```

So running:

```
mmdev 8 0
```

prints...

```
b:8:0:/dev/sda
```

Here's the first one I wrote.

```
majminpath() {
    set -- ${1##*[!0-9]*} ${2##*[!0-9]*}
    udevadm info --export-db |
    sed 's|^[^=]*DEVNAME=||
         \|^[^/]|!h;/MAJOR=/N
         \|='"$1\n.*=${2?}"'$|!d;g'
}
```

This just scans `udevadm info --export-db` output for the matching numbers. The output looks like:

```
P: /devices/virtual/vc/vcsa4
N: vcsa4
E: DEVNAME=/dev/vcsa4
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/vc/vcsa4
E: MAJOR=7
E: MINOR=132
E: SUBSYSTEM=vc

P: /devices/virtual/vc/vcsa5
N: vcsa5
E: DEVNAME=/dev/vcsa5
E: DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/vc/vcsa5
E: MAJOR=7
E: MINOR=133
E: SUBSYSTEM=vc

#...and so on
```

The workflow is like:

- attempt to strip the `[^=]*DEVNAME=` string from the head of each line
- if a line does not have a first character or its first character is `/` copy that line over `h`old space
- if a line matches `MAJOR=` append `N`ext input line to pattern space
- if there are 2 lines in pattern space that match `=$1\n.*=$2$` then copy `h`old space over pattern space and auto-print; else delete pattern space

So if I do:

```
majminpath 7 133 ; majminpath 8 0 ; majminpath 8 1
```

#### OUTPUT

```
/dev/vcsa5
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1
```

But, as @xae points out, block/char type devices can share maj:min combinations, and so this might possibly print more than one path per call.

Comment: Unfortunately it's no so easy, a block and a character device can share the same major number. Take a look at the file /proc/devices.

Comment: I gotta check subsystem - that's right. Thanks, @xae.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you mean.

```
mknod foo b 8 0
```

Will create the device file called `foo` as a block device with major 8 and minor 0. If you mean to find one or any of the files in `/dev` that have the same type, major and minor, you can do  (with `zsh`):

- For block device `8:0`:

  ```
  $ zmodload zsh/stat
  $ ls -ld /dev/**/*(-D%be:'zstat -H s $REPLY && (($s[rdev] == 8<<8+0))':)
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    6 Aug 23 05:28 /dev/block/8:0 -> ../sda
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Aug 23 05:28 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-KINGSTON_SNV455S234GB_07MA10014418 -> ../../sda
  brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Aug 23 05:28 /dev/sda
  ```
- for char device `226:0`:

  ```
  $ ls -ld /dev/**/*(-D%ce:'zstat -H s $REPLY && (($s[rdev] == 226<<8+0))':)
  lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      12 Aug 23 05:28 /dev/char/226:0 -> ../dri/card0
  crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226, 0 Aug 23 05:28 /dev/dri/card0
  ```

Note that anything can create files in `/dev`. In the very old days, it was a script creating static files in there. At some point, you even had a special file system à la `/proc`.

On modern versions of Linux, it's usually `udev` based on input from the kernel.

The name it chooses for the base device file is based on the `DEVNAME` supplied by the kernel. `udev` rules may change that but generally don't, and some `udev` rules will add some more symlinks for convenience (like the `/dev/disk/by...` ones).

You can go from major:minor to kernel `DEVNAME` by looking at:

```
$ sed -n 's/^DEVNAME=//p' /sys/dev/block/8:0/uevent
sda
$ sed -n 's/^DEVNAME=//p' /sys/dev/char/226:0/uevent
dri/card0
```

You can also get that information from the `udev` database as mikeserv has shown.

Answer (score 1):

*Alas*, the `/sys/dev` hierachy was only added to the kernel as late as 2.6.27 (*cf.* the relevant [commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=e105b8bfc769b0545b6f0f395179d1e43cbee822) against the kernel codebase), so we need a “bifurcated” approach.

Let `$M` and `$m`, respectively, be the major and minor number of our device file.

#### *Post* 2.6.27 kernels

As suggested by others, the simplest approach unleashes the power of the `sysfs` “virtual” file system, by chasing straight for files named `$M:$m` under the folder `/sys/dev` (more than one file is to be expected if we don't know whether our device is a character- or a block-based one), and then sourcing the `uevent` file (in a subshell so as to prevent namespace pollution):

```
for file in $(find /sys/dev/ -name $M:$m)
do
    (
        source ${file}/uevent
        echo $DEVNAME
    )
done
```

#### *Pre* 2.6.27 kernels

Let us assume, for simplicity's sake, that our file is a *block* device (a similar approach applies for character devices).  We will search for the string `$M:$m` throughout the `/sys/block` hierarchy, by examining (underneath that folder) the contents of every file whose name happens to be `dev`.  If `/sys/block/<...>/<DEV>/dev` is one such file, then `DEV` is bound to be our device's name:

```
dirname "$(find "/sys/block" -name dev | xargs -r grep -l ^$M:$m$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux it is possible to take advantage of certain files in `/proc` virtual filesystem.

```
$ grep '8[[:blank:]]\+1[[:blank:]]\+' /proc/partitions 
   8        1   29309568 sda1

$ grep '8:1[[:blank:]]' /proc/self/mountinfo 
28 0 8:1 / / rw,relatime shared:1 - ext4 /dev/sda1 rw,data=ordered
```

The simple form of the pattern already provides information about the desired device in the output, however additional filtering to extract just one particular string is possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library function: `makedev()`

```
#include <sys/sysmacros.h>
dev_t makedev(unsigned int maj, unsigned int min);
```

Given major and minor device IDs, makedev() combines these to produce a device ID, returned as the function result.

For more details visit: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/major.3.html