# convert MAJ:MIN – device numbers to real disks names

Tags: linux, rhel, hard-disk, disk, sar

from sar command on saX file we can get the disks utilization as the follwing

```
sar -d -f /var/log/sa/sa18  | grep Average
Average:       dev8-0      1.24      0.00    150.06    121.40      0.04     30.40      4.72      0.58
Average:     dev253-0      0.32      0.00      3.75     11.83      0.01     17.95      3.48      0.11
Average:     dev253-1      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:     dev253-2      1.12      0.00    146.31    130.68      0.04     31.79      4.46      0.50
Average:      dev8-16      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:      dev8-32      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:      dev8-48      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:     dev253-3      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

we can see that disks defined as MAJ:MIN  as ( dev8-16 , dev8-48 , etc )

is it possible to get the real disks name as sdb , sdc sdc , etc ? using the `sar` cli  ( `sar -d -f /var/log/sa/sa18  | grep Average` )

Comment: (Go for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151819/106650) answer, not for the accepted one, i.e. a simple `udevadm info -rq name /sys/dev/block/MAJ:MIN` does it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

devrez()
{
    l=/sys/dev/block/`echo "$1" | sed 's/dev//g;s/-/:/g'`
    test ! -L "$l" && echo "[$1] not found" && return -1
    readlink -f "$l" | awk -F / '{ORS="";print "\t"$NF}'
}

export -f devrez

sar -d -f /var/log/sa/sa18 | awk '{OFS="\t";ORS="";print $1; system("/bin/bash -c '\''devrez "$2"'\''");$1="";$2="";print "";print;print "\n"}'
```

Comment: since we are using python script, do you think its possible to do the same in pytyon instead of what you wrote in bash ?

Comment: Sorry, my python fu is missing :-) This should be easier to do in python actually.

Comment: ok np , I will try it in python but I am stuck to do something similar to export -f devrez

Comment: You don't need to use this function in python, it has a `os.readlink()` method. Instead of AWK, you use `split()`. It must be easy. My script uses sed to `dev253-0` -> `253:0`, this could be done with `.replace()`.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation `man sar` tells you how to get name lookups for `sar -d`:

> **`-d`** Report  activity for each block device. When data are displayed, the device name is displayed as it (should) appear in `/dev`. `sar` uses data in `/sys` to determine the device name based on its major and minor numbers.   If this name  resolution  fails, `sar` will use name mapping controlled by `/etc/sysstat/sysstat.ioconf` file.  Persistent device names can also be printed if option `-j` is used […]

In summary,

1. It should already happen
2. If it doesn't you can add them to `/etc/sysstat/sysstat.ioconf`
3. You might prefer to use one of the `-j {option}` options such as `LABEL`.

I've recently enabled system accounting on a Pi that I have here. Obviously the statistics run is not significant but I can already see that on this machine the disk names are correctly displayed:

```
sar -d -f /var/log/sysstat/sa18
Linux 4.9.35-v7+ (pi)   18/01/23        _armv7l_        (4 CPU)

12:16:05     LINUX RESTART      (4 CPU)

12:40:01          DEV       tps     rkB/s     wkB/s     dkB/s   areq-sz    aqu-sz     await     %util
12:42:08      mmcblk0      3.37     14.35     19.58      0.00     10.06      0.08     23.15      0.58
12:42:08         dm-0      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:      mmcblk0      3.37     14.35     19.58      0.00     10.06      0.08     23.15      0.58
Average:         dm-0      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

I wonder if you have copied the `sa*` files to a different server for analysis, perhaps? In which case you may indeed need to edit `sysstat.ioconf` to name them.